# How to open a connection to a WebSocket server in Crystal (use Crystal as client)

Tags: websocket, crystal-lang

I would like to consume a websocket server connection using Crystal as a client. Does the Crystal standard library provide a WebSocket client library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Crystal 0.8.0 you should be able to:

```
socket = HTTP::WebSocket.open("example.com", "/connect")
socket.send "action"
message = socket.receive
```

See https://github.com/manastech/crystal/pull/1369 for more details.

Comment: wrong number of arguments for 'HTTP::WebSocket#receive' (0 for 1)
Overloads are:
 - HTTP::WebSocket#receive(buffer : Slice(UInt8))

    message = socket.receive()
                     ^~~~~~~
ANy ideas on this one?

Comment: Sorry, it reads from the websocket into a buffer. eg: `buf = Slice(UInt8).new; ws.read(buf);` There is no buffered IO that would read just a message and block until one is ready, yet.

Comment: @JulienPortalier what's the best way to do with the latest version of crystal?